# (Tauri) API request with ignoring the SSL certificate (https)

Tags: https, axios, ssl-certificate, vite, tauri

I creating a Tauri app that makes a request via https protocol to the controller with required SSL certificate.
Now I can ignore the certificate, but in the future I will need to support it and be able to add it.

I using Tauri with Vite.

I'm moving from Electron to Tauri and previously I used Axios to ignore the certificate I used https agent but I don't know how to use it in Tauri.

I tried several solutions:

1. Tauri http module

```
import { getClient } from '@tauri-apps/api/http'; const client = await getClient(); const response = await client.delete('https://192.168.100.100/');
```

It throws an error: `Uncaught (in promise) Network Error: Tls Error` 
I suspected an error because it's an http module, not https.

2. Tauri axios adapter

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosTauriAdapter from 'axios-tauri-adapter';
const client = axios.create({ adapter: axiosTauriAdapter });

document.getElementById("get-ata").addEventListener("click", api_get_ata)
function  api_get_ata(){
    axios.get("https://192.168.100.100/")
    .then(function (response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```

It also throws the error: `GET https://192.168.100.100/ net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`
and there is a similar error from Axios.
I tried adding option to axios that ignore the certificate, but it doesn't do anything.

3. Rust backend

```
#[tauri::command]
fn api_post_req(url: &str, auth: &str, body: String, timeout: f32) -> String
{ 
  let client = Client::builder()
    .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
    .build()
    .unwrap();

  let time: Duration = Duration::from_secs_f32(timeout);

  let result = client
    .post(url)
    .header("authorization", auth)
    .body(body)
    .timeout(time)
    .send();

  return convert_response(result)
}

fn convert_response(result: Result<Response, Error>) -> String {
  return match result {
    Ok(response) => {
      match response.text() {
        Ok(text) => {
          text
        }
        Err(err) => {
          "Something messed up! but result was ok. Rust error:".to_string() + err.to_string().as_str()
        }
      }
    },
    Err(error) => {
      "Rust error: ".to_string() + error.to_string().as_str()
    }
  }
}
```

It works but it isn't async and when I make a request every 300ms, the whole application freezes. I am not a Rust guy and I don't want write in it, to make it async.

I looking for a better solution